# Django Allauth google error: SocialApp matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Setting up oauth2 for google with `django-allauth` getting an error when I click `google` [image]

Can see the login page and the social auth settings [image] the error log below

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/views.py" in view
  69.                 return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/views.py" in dispatch
  92.         app = provider.get_app(self.request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/base.py" in get_app
  52.         return SocialApp.objects.get_current(self.id, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/models.py" in get_current
  38.                 provider=provider)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  387.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /accounts/google/login/
Exception Value: SocialApp matching query does not exist.
```

**UPDATE**

Settings file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.paypal',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',

    'django.contrib.admin',

    'django_countries',

    'accounts'
)
```

and google settings

[image]

**UPDATE**

Editing the social path domain from sub-domain to main `kazichimp.com` creates a url mismatch below. Possibly oauth works only on the main domain.

[image]

Comment: what does you settings.py look like?
what are your settings at Google oauth?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: solved the issue make sure to use the redirect url as such `http://example.com/accounts/twitter/login/callback/` depending on the provider